# Java.io.filenotfoundexception filepath (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file-handling, java-io

I have made .exe file (using launchj4  and inno install creater). In java file (Netbeans Project) it works properly I can edit and change data but when I try to use it in exe file it give Exception it only reads file.

It also shows exact path of Customer.txt and other 2 but when I try to write it gives:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Customer.txt(Access Denied)

Code:

```
public DataInOut()
    {
    customer = new File("Customer.txt");
    Sale = new File("SaleReport.txt");
    Salesman = new File("SaleMan.txt");
    path_Customer = customer.getAbsolutePath();
    path_Sale = Salesman.getAbsolutePath();
    path_Report = Sale.getAbsolutePath();
    WriteCustomer = new File(path_Customer);
    WriteSale = new File(path_Report);
    WriteSalesMan = new File(path_Sale);
}

public void dataIn()
{
    try{
        int i =0;
        CR = new FileReader(customer);
        CBR = new BufferedReader(CR);
        boolean check = true;
        while(check)
        {
                String text = CBR.readLine();
                if(text!=null)
                {
                    String[] arr = text.split("=");
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(arr[5]);
                    arr_customer[index] = text;
                    arr_index[i] = index;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                    check = false;
        }
        CBR.close();
        CR.close();

        i = 0;
        SaleR = new FileReader(Sale);
        SaleBR = new BufferedReader(SaleR);
        check = true;
        while(check)
        {
            String text = SaleBR.readLine();
            if(text!=null)
            {
                arr_report[i] = text;
                i++;
            }
            else
                check = false;
        }
        SaleBR.close();
        SaleR.close();
        i = 0;
        SR = new FileReader(Salesman);
        SBR = new BufferedReader(SR);
        check = true;
        while(check)
        {
            String text = SBR.readLine();
            if(text!=null)
            {
                arr_Saleman[i] = text;
                i++;
            }
            else
                check = false;
        }
        SBR.close();
        SR.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

public void dataOut()
{
    try{
        int i = 0;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(WriteCustomer,false);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("");
        bw.close();
        fw.close();

        CW = new FileWriter(WriteCustomer,true);
        CBW = new BufferedWriter(CW);
        CBW.flush();
        while(arr_index[i]!=0)
        {
            CBW.write(arr_customer[arr_index[i]]);
            CBW.newLine();
            i++;
        }
        CBW.close();
        CW.close();


        FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(WriteSale,false);
        BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
        bw2.write("");
        bw2.close();
        fw2.close();
        i = 0;
        SaleW = new FileWriter(WriteSale,true);
        saleBW = new BufferedWriter(SaleW);
        saleBW.flush();
        while(arr_report[i]!=null)
        {
            saleBW.write(arr_report[i]);
            saleBW.newLine();
            i++;
        }
        saleBW.close();
        SaleW.close();

        FileWriter fw3 = new FileWriter(WriteSalesMan,false);
        BufferedWriter bw3 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
        bw3.write("");
        bw3.close();
        fw3.close();
        i = 0;
        SW = new FileWriter(WriteSalesMan,true);
        SBW = new BufferedWriter(SW);
        SBW.flush();
        while(arr_Saleman[i]!=null)
        {
            SBW.write(arr_Saleman[i]);
            SBW.newLine();
            i++;
        }
        SBW.close();
        SW.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have file at location `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Customer.txt` or your application has rights to access this file?

Comment: Change => `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(WriteCustomer,false);` TO `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(customer,false);`
and let me know the output

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.